# Get current loaded octets in angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

I have a big file loaded with angular $http. I want to see the current octets loaded each seconds for example.

The [$http doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) says:

> Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http
>   specific methods: success and error

But what I want is a notifyCallback like in [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

I have:

```
var myPromise = $http.get(url);

myPromise.then(function(){
  // success
}, function() {
  //error
});
```

Comment: The Promise progression API is being deprecated since it didn't particularly work or compose well (in favor of estimation. You can wrap your own XMLHttpRequest and get the loaded octets easily.